# AFHTTPSessionManager with Cache Policy not working

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

Server sends cache header in response.

"Cache-Control": "max-age=120, public"

First I used NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad with the AFHTTPRequestOperation.

By setting shared cache in AppDelegate and setting the NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad in the NSUrlRequest.

It worked fine.

But when i tried to do the same with AFHTTPSessionManager by setting NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad in the following ways,

1.**request.session.configuration.requestCachePolicy**

2.**request.requestSerializer.cachePolicy**

3.Overriding **-(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *, id, NSError *))completionHandler**

Nothing seems to be working.

AFNetworking version - 2.5.1

Comment: which version of afnetworking ?

Comment: afnetworking version 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after hours of searching, I have found that AFHTTPSessionManager uses cookies to cache requests.

Simply deleted all cookies and it all worked.

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [storage cookies]) {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
```